# Convert the Mono<List<PojoA>> to List<PojoB>

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux, reactive

I have a `Mono<List<PojoA>>` object. I need to iterate the list of `PojoA and` form a new `List<String>`

```
    public List<String> getImageList() {
    
        Mono<List<PojoA>> pojoAListMono = someMethod();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        pojoAListMono.flatMapMany(imageList -> {
          imageList.stream().forEach(image -> list.add("/images/" + image.getImageName()));
        });
      }
```

Comment: i need to return List<String> from this method

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: as I understood, flatMapMany return flux. I'm not able to return imageList inside the flatMapMany block. Its show compilation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you requesting to do (going from a stream to a list of objects)
is not suggested because you lose the power of reactive (async) converting to a blocking state.

but sure you can do that using.block()
below is an

```
            public List<String> getImageList() {
               return someMethod()
               .flatMapIterable(pojoAS -> pojoAS)
               .map(pojoA -> "/images/"+pojoA.getImageName())
               .collectList()
               .block();
            }
```